# SQL attributes depending on type

Tags: sql, attributes

Let's say I have an entity CLIENT, which can be either PERSON or ORGANIZATION. Depending on which type it is, I have to choose attributes (address, name for organization, date_of_birth,first_name,last_name for person). I have created all three entities, but how can I make the attributes type-dependent?

Seen [Database design: objects with different attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2714206/1319392), didn't help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One typical choice is a `1:1` extension table:

```
create table client (id int primary key);
create table person (id int foreign key references client(id), ...columns...);
create table organization (id int foreign key references client(id), ...columns...);
```

However, my preferred choice is to include all columns in the `client` table.  You can have a column for type that is either `person` or `organization`.  Columns that are not relevant for the row's type can be null.  Your queries will be much simpler that way.

Comment: I am actually writing a database of room rent. In this case organization or person can be not only client, but also the room provider. So in this case do I have to have two references?

Answer (score 2):

Either you use 3 tables or you use 1 table and leave the not needed columns null. Which design is superior depends on the use case. Using only 1 table gives simpler queries but requires to change the table for each new subclass. Using multiple tables allows to add more types easily but gives more complicated queries. In doubt I would start with only 1 table but your mileage may vary.